# How to mask a map field by Fieldmask in Python protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to mask a protobuf message using `FieldMask` in Python.

## proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Msg {

    message ImageInfo {
        string url = 1;
        int32 width = 2;
        int32 height = 3;
    }

    string name = 1;
    map<string, ImageInfo> image_info = 2;
}
```

Masking `string` field can be successfully done.

```
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2
import msg_pb2

original_msg = msg_pb2.Msg(name='image-0')
original_msg.image_info['main'].url = 'http://example.com/image-0.jpg'
original_msg.image_info['main'].width = 10
original_msg.image_info['main'].height = 10

field_mask=field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['name'])
new_msg = msg_pb2.Msg()
field_mask.MergeMessage(original_msg, new_msg)
```

But, masking `map<string, message>` field fails.

```
field_mask=field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['name', 'image_info'])
new_msg = msg_pb2.Msg()
field_mask.MergeMessage(original_msg, new_msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/opt/project/test-1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py", line 473, in MergeMessage
    source, destination, replace_message_field, replace_repeated_field)   File "/opt/project/test-1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py", line 625, in MergeMessage
    self._root, source, destination, replace_message, replace_repeated)   File "/opt/project/test-1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py", line 667, in _MergeMessage
    repeated_destination.add().MergeFrom(item) AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageMapContainer' object has no attribute 'add'
```

How to mask it ?

## Edit

One solution is wrapper message. But It's a little bother.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Msg {

    message ImageInfo {
        string url = 1;
        int32 width = 2;
        int32 height = 3;
    }
    message ImageInfoContainer {
        map<string, ImageInfo> image_info = 1;
    }

    string name = 1;
    ImageInfoContainer image_info = 2;
}
```